# How to subtract lines with thickness from polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, differences

I have a polygon and some lines crossing it. I want to subtract the lines with a certain "thickness" from the polygon, so it splits up into various polygons which do not touch each other anymore. You can see the two situations in this picture:

[image: Result of the difference between line and polygon]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: First buffer the lines, then subtract (Difference) the buffer polygon from your original polygon (p0).

Comment: @Erica please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as resolved

Answer (score 4):

1. [Buffer](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Buffer_with_QGIS) the lines.
2. Use Difference to subtract the buffer polygon from the original polygon (p0).